# Help with a Pearson's chi-square test exercise

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

The following exercise is from some assessment test from Hong Kong.  It looked like a GOF test at first, but I've only ever done them with a single column of data.  I'm a maths tutor but I had to transfer him since I didn't recognize the correct procedure.  And of course I would like that not to happen again, so, can anyone show me the correct way to approach this problem?  Here it is:

**Exercise.**  *A random sample of 230 workers at a company were surveyed about their satisfaction with their life.  The answer about their satisfaction was recorded along with their annual wages:*
$$
\begin{array}{lccccr}
 & \$\text{20-35k} & \$\text{35-50k} & \$\text{50-75k} & \$\text{75-90k} & \text{Total}
\\ 
\text{Very satisfied} & 13 & 11 & 19 & 15 & 58
\\
\text{Somewhat satisfied} & 29 & 31 & 28 & 12 & 100
\\
\text{Not satisfied} & 34 & 20 & 10 & 8 & 72
\\
\text{Total} & 76 & 62 & 57 & 35 & 230
\\\hline
\text{Pearson's Chi-square test} & \chi^2=20.0043 & \text{df}=6 & \text{p-value}<0.001
\end{array}
$$
*Assuming there's no relationship between income and life satisfaction, how many people who earn between $20-35k would you expect to be 'not satisfied' with life?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you are a 'tutor' you know this is a textbook problem and so that the question should have some context. After a minute or two with the textbook, you might have offered an attempt at solution for us to check.

Comment: @BruceET I don't understand. Why did you put 'tutor' in scare quotes?  And what textbook?

Comment: Tiny little one-stroke quotes, didn't intend them to be scary. You said attempt to tutor was only temporary before 'transferring' him. If you're trying to tutor, isn't it best to look at lecture notes or text to get as much of the story as possible? If no text, what source for quoted question? // Main issue now is whether Answer was of any help.

Comment: @BruceET Well, it was an assessment from a student in Hong Kong, and we were chatting remotely.  So, there was no textbook in this context, and even if there was, I wouldn't have had access to it.  As for the answers, I still have to read them, but I definitely will.  I've just been busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The expected values are defined as the the frequencies that should be found in each cell of the table assuming no association between the two variables.

The expected value for each cell is obtained by multiplying the row total to the column total, and then dividing by the grand total.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.  In the mean time, can you recommend a textbook with the complete procedure for me to follow?

Comment: Give a look at https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/chis-quared-tests-of-association.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjayZ-jl9LrAhWJLsAKHSnEDeAQFjAJegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1EqotpHhe-yB73YydGcGb4

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below is analysis of this data table using the `chisq.test` procedure in R.
Nothing here is classified 'secret'; formulas for everything should be in
the course textbook.

**Data table:**

```
vs = c(13,11,19,15)
ss = c(29,31,28,12)
ns = c(34,20,10, 8)
TBL = rbind(vs,ss,ns);  TBL
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
vs   13   11   19   15
ss   29   31   28   12
ns   34   20   10    8
rowSums(TBL)
vs  ss  ns 
58 100  72 
colSums(TBL)
[1] 76 62 57 35
```

**Chi-squared test:**

The test statistic (`X-sq` in printout) is
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^r\sum_{j=1}^c \frac{(X_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}},$$
where the table has $r = 3$ rows and $c = 4$ columns, $X_{ij}$ are
observed cell counts, and $E_{ij}$ are expected counts determined
from table row and column totals in accordance with the null hypothesis.

Provided that all $E_{ij} \ge 5,$ the test statistic $Q$ has approximately
a chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu = (r-1)(c-1) = 6.$

```
chi.out = chisq.test(TBL); chi.out

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 20.008, df = 6, p-value = 0.00276
```

Notice that you can match the output here with results included in your Question.
The expected counts $E_{ij}$ are available:

```
chi.out$exp
       [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]
vs 19.16522 15.63478 14.37391  8.826087
ss 33.04348 26.95652 24.78261 15.217391
ns 23.79130 19.40870 17.84348 10.956522
```

In particular, following @Anatoly's response (+1), $E_{31} = \frac{76(72)}{230} =  23.7913,$
can be obtained from appropriate row and column totals of the table.

**Figure:** Below is a plot of the density function of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 6)$ along with
the 5% critical value of the test (vertical dotted line) and the observed value
of $Q = 20.01$ (solid line). The 95th quantile $c = 12.5916$ of the chi-squared distribution
can be found in printed tables of chi-squared distributions or from R (see below).

```
qchisq(.95, 6)
[1] 12.59159
```

The exact P-value (here $0.003),$ often shown in computer printouts, cannot usually be found from printed tables. The value from R is shown below:

```
1 - pchisq(20.008, 6)
[1] 0.00276033
```

In the figure below the area to the right of $c$ under the chi-squared density curve
is 5% and the (very small) area to the right of $Q$ is $0.003.$

[image]